# Foreach json getting a lot of errors: Trying to get property of non-object / Undefined property

Tags: php, arrays, json, spotify

I'm trying to fetch the name and artists of all the tracks on a spotify playlist.

I have no problem fetching the name of the playlist, the coverart, the total count of followers.

But when I try to fetch the name and artist i get this line of errors

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/rasmuspedersen/Dropbox/www/life/mobil/json.php on line 14

```
my code is 
$string = file_get_contents("playlist.json");
        $json=json_decode($string);
        echo $json->followers->total.'<br />';
        foreach($json->images as $image){
            echo '<img src="'.$image->url.'" /><br>';
        }
        echo $json->name.'<br />';

        $i = 0;

        foreach($json->tracks->items as $tracks){

            foreach($tracks->track as $track) {
                echo($track->name);
            };

        if(++$i > 1) break; 
        };`
```

And my JSON is this
http://wecre8.it/playlist.json

I can't find the problem, and I tried google.

Hope someone can find my error and help fetch the artist and titles of the tracks in the playlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example JSON, the `track` object is under the `items` array and not under `tracks` object as what your code is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = file_get_contents ( 'playlist.json' );
$array = json_decode ( $string, TRUE );
```